# Why do some large websites use .html extension?

Tags: url, seo

I'm just curious... why do some large sites (high traffic, a lot of data) use .html extension on their pages even though it's is clear that it's interpreted by php on the server side?

For example [metrolyrics.com/top100.html](http://www.metrolyrics.com/top100.html)

It's pretty clear that it uses php on the back-end, but still got .html suffix.

Is it better for SEO? Or am I wrong about the back-end and these pages are really static HTMLs as their extension says?

Every opinion is welcomed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Chances are the site is built using a server-side language, but they're generating static files to avoid the parsing overhead when thousands of users visit the same URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metrolyrics might not necessarily be using PHP for its back-end. It could be using other server side languages such as Ruby or Python.

I'd say one of the main reasons for not having PHP in a websites url is for protection. It is more difficult for people to hack a website if they don't know what language is being used on the back-end.

Secondly, websites tend to look more professional if they don't have an extension. And it raises less questions for end users. It's true that people are more used to seeing .html at the end of a URL, users may get more confused if they see .php instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was a well known convention back in the day where static HTML pages were highly regarded for seo. Basically what they done was to keep thousands of these generated HTML pages on the server, making the website look like a content monster and thus elevating its Page Rank and the amount of google scans.

It's also a good way to cache pages and decrease server calls.